# Stuck on creating multistore Magento

Tags: magento

I'm running Magento 1.6.2. and my server is running Nginx. I am not using .htaccess files, so I have to make my changes in index.php.

After setting up the proper stores, storeviews and making changes, all looks well. When opening website_a.com, I see storeview_a. Which is good. But when opening website_b.com, at first it still loads website_a.com. :-( I've been checking store URL configuration under System > Configuration > Web, and that's okay. Help!!!

```
umask(0);

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "website_a.com"){
$_SERVER["MAGE_RUN_CODE"] = "store_a";
$_SERVER["MAGE_RUN_TYPE"] = "storeview_a";
}

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "website_b.com"){
$_SERVER["MAGE_RUN_CODE"] = "store_a";
$_SERVER["MAGE_RUN_TYPE"] = "storeview_b";
}

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

Answer (score 0):

The MAGE_RUN_TYPE should be 'website' or 'store' and it specify which ID/code type you put in MAGE_RUN_CODE. For example:

```
"MAGE_RUN_CODE" = "storeview_code";
"MAGE_RUN_TYPE" = "store";
```

or

```
"MAGE_RUN_CODE" = "website_code";
"MAGE_RUN_TYPE" = "website";
```

When you use MAGE_RUN_TYPE - website, the default website storeview used.

> I've been checking store URL configuration under System >
>   Configuration > Web, and that's okay

Note that, this URLs used only for URL building and redirects. But all routing, assigning correct URLs to store views / websites should be done manually.